# getting error : You cannot attach a PaymentMethod to a Customer during PaymentMethod creation. in recurring payment intent stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on recurring payment intent, when i am trying to `Charge the saved card later Server-side`, I am getting this response  :

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => You cannot attach a PaymentMethod to a Customer during PaymentMethod creation. Please instead create the PaymentMethod and then attach it using the attachment method of the PaymentMethods API.
            [type] => invalid_request_error
        )

)
```

for that i have use curl method

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods \
  -u ********: \
  -d customer="{{CUSTOMER_ID}}" \
  -d type=card
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? I have refer this page

```
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem.. according to their [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach), we need to first create a payment method and then attach it with the customer. Though, don't know then why they have provided customer field

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this link might have a solution, it's better to add code here, and explaining it.